# Masonry layout shadow get clipping

Tags: html, css, masonry

I am creating a masonry layout with shadow. But unfortunately, the shadow gets clipped as the following snippet. I know that put some bottom padding will fix this, but the content of this card can be change time to time then the height will change according to the content. So the problem here needed a pure CSS method to get rid of bottom clipping in any height and content size.

Thanks

[image]

```css
.masonry-cascading-grid-layout {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    
    padding-bottom: 120px; 
    
    .masonry-wrap{
      padding-bottom: 120px; 
    }
  }

  .item-masonry {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    
    box-shadow: 0px 30px 60px -30px #757287, 0px 10px 100px -20px rgba(0,0,0,.25);//shadow
    
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

    .masonry-cascading-grid-layout {
      -moz-column-count: 2;
      -webkit-column-count: 2;
      column-count: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="masonry-cascading-grid-layout">
      <div class="masonry-wrap">
                          <div class="item-masonry">
            <h3 class="title">Item 1</h3>
            <div class="content"><p>Ut id cursus ligula, sit amet pharetra nisi. Proin in orci vitae ipsum suscipit laoreet ac at risus. Nullam convallis nibh a tortor volutpat, at maximus justo pharetra. Donec eros tellus, scelerisque at mauris non, mollis mollis velit. <br><br> Praesent fringilla orci vitae ligula ultrices finibus a id risus. Praesent sed quam pharetra, pulvinar diam iaculis, condimentum eros. Duis accumsan rutrum aliquam. Donec id quam odio. Pellentesque euismod lectus eget sem luctus dapibus. Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh pretium in.</p></div>
          </div>
                  <div class="item-masonry">
            <h3 class="title">Item 2</h3>
            <div class="content"><p>Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on pretium in.</p></div>
          </div>
                  <div class="item-masonry">
            <h3 class="title">Item 3</h3>
            <div class="content"><p>No</p></div>
          </div>
                  <div class="item-masonry">
            <h3 class="title">Item 4</h3>
            <div class="content"><p>Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on pretium in.<br>Ut id cursus ligula, sit amet pharetra nisi. Proin in orci vitae ipsum suscipit laoreet ac at risus. Nullam convallis nibh a tortor volutpat, at maximus justo pharetra. Donec eros tellus, scelerisque at mauris non, mollis mollis velit.</p></div>
          </div>
                  <div class="item-masonry">
            <h3 class="title">Item 5</h3>
            <div class="content"><p>Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on pretium in.</p></div>
          </div>
              </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This problem took me a lot of time to find a fix. I googled at lot to find all the necessary properties that finally helped me achieve this. This was challenging though. May be you need some minor changes with this later, but you will only have to decide which div to be kept as position:relative; that's it. Do rate and accept the answer. And Happy coding to you :). This question has a bounty. I am also feeling proud today. My first answer with bounty. Stay Blessed. God bless Coders :)

Comment: I think its the padding on the bottom of the container, just add more padding so it can show the shadow, i believe this is also imran's answers ;) so thumbs up.

Comment: you are spread box shadow too much I think you have to reduce the spread width of the shadow, and second thing is that your first box shadow is overlapping on nearest box so if you want to have same shadow spread width then you have to increase the gutter width too. it looks too much wearied.

Comment: @Rmaxx: Hi there :) I have not used padding since the questioner doesn't want to use it. I kind of overlayed a div on clipped edge of the parent and added blur() and box-shdow on it. This is my Idea to tackle it. Stay Blessed Mate:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to do this again with myself. I cannot accept Imran answer because it is tricky but not a good code practice. (Thanks for your support Imran, But I start from scratch to build this again.)
I found a good article (https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/masonry-with-css/) written by Tobias Ahlin Bjerrome and it gives the knowledge all I need. Change `display: inline-block;` to `flex` and remove the outer wrapper was fix the issue. Now it looks cleaner and less

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  /* Your container needs a fixed height, and it 
   * needs to be taller than your tallest column. */
  height: 1000px;
  counter-reset: items;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  width: 49%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 60px -30px #757287,
    0px 10px 100px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
     <h3 class="title">Item 1</h3>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Ut id cursus ligula, sit amet pharetra nisi. Proin in orci vitae ipsum suscipit laoreet ac at risus. Nullam convallis nibh a tortor volutpat, at maximus justo pharetra. Donec eros tellus, scelerisque at mauris non, mollis mollis velit. <br><br> Praesent fringilla orci vitae ligula ultrices finibus a id risus. Praesent sed quam pharetra, pulvinar diam iaculis, condimentum eros. Duis accumsan rutrum aliquam. Donec id quam odio. Pellentesque euismod lectus eget sem luctus dapibus. Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh pretium in.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <h3 class="title">Item 2</h3>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on pretium in.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <h3 class="title">Item 3</h3>
    <div class="content">
      <p>No</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <h3 class="title">Item 4</h3>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on pretium in.<br>Ut id cursus ligula, sit amet pharetra nisi. Proin in orci vitae ipsum suscipit laoreet ac at risus. Nullam convallis nibh a tortor volutpat, at maximus justo pharetra. Donec eros tellus, scelerisque at mauris non, mollis mollis velit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <h3 class="title">Item 5</h3>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on pretium in.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this kind of clipping of `box-shadow` is because the parent element.

I have came up with the fix for this finally:

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Enjoy the below code:

```css
body {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.masonry-cascading-grid-layout {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.item-masonry {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;

  box-shadow: 0px 30px 60px -30px #757287,
    0px 10px 100px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

  border-radius: 5px;
}

.masonry-cascading-grid-layout {
  column-count: 2;
}

.quick-fix {
  height: 10px;  
  width: 51%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.5rem;
  left: -0.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 28px #ccc;
  filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="masonry-cascading-grid-layout">
      <div class="masonry-wrap">
        <div class="item-masonry">
          <h3 class="title">Item 1</h3>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Ut id cursus ligula, sit amet pharetra nisi. Proin in orci vitae
              ipsum suscipit laoreet ac at risus. Nullam convallis nibh a tortor
              volutpat, at maximus justo pharetra. Donec eros tellus,
              scelerisque at mauris non, mollis mollis velit.
              <br /><br />
              Praesent fringilla orci vitae ligula ultrices finibus a id risus.
              Praesent sed quam pharetra, pulvinar diam iaculis, condimentum
              eros. Duis accumsan rutrum aliquam. Donec id quam odio.
              Pellentesque euismod lectus eget sem luctus dapibus. Vestibulum
              sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor quam. Orci
              varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
              ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in
              faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus vehicula. Vivamus
              scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh pretium in.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-masonry">
          <h3 class="title">Item 2</h3>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor
              quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
              montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
              ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus
              vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on
              pretium in.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-masonry">
          <h3 class="title">Item 3</h3>
          <div class="content"><p>No</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-masonry">
          <h3 class="title">Item 4</h3>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor
              quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
              montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
              ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus
              vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on
              pretium in.<br />Ut id cursus ligula, sit amet pharetra nisi.
              Proin in orci vitae ipsum suscipit laoreet ac at risus. Nullam
              convallis nibh a tortor volutpat, at maximus justo pharetra. Donec
              eros tellus, scelerisque at mauris non, mollis mollis velit.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-masonry">
          <h3 class="title">Item 5</h3>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              Vestibulum sit amet velit feugiat, bibendum arcu interdum, auctor
              quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
              montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
              ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porttitor dapibus
              vehicula. Vivamus scelerisque metus lectus, vel cursus nibh on
              pretium in.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Fix to bottom clipper -->
      <div class="quick-fix"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <!-- <script src="./script.js"></script> -->
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Imran. Thanks for your commitment and answer, this is tricky.

Comment: Dear Isuru, I didn't slept the whole night for this one. I had to come up with the solution for this, because this issue occurs a lot of times. I also noticed that on the start of the parent div, there is also the same clipping, which you may have also noticed. We can use the same trick for that also. we just have to use top:-3px; left:0; for that div. Do, please accept the answer and rate. Other developers will benefit from it as well :) Thank you

Comment: Oh man sorry. I am not thinking this is the solution. Because it applies to both columns. Left and right. But I will give the bounty marks. Because you are the only person that give a try on this. If you can fix that only to apply in the left column and sticky with the bottom I will accept. (because clipping happen only left side of this layout) I try a lot but unfortunately, I am not clever enough to fix that. If you have time give a try. It will good for you. Thanks, Imran.

Comment: That's easy my friend, I actually did that part initially :) Let me help you with that. And one this. You are a wonderful person, Being clever or not is a different thing. It's just that Sometimes the idea did not click. Let me do it for you my friend. Let me check the code again. And There is in fact a better solution for this overall using CSS-Grid masonry. Then the approach to do it will be quite different. But let's fix this one for now

Comment: Have updated as per the latest change dear Friend :) It is working  on half the side only on all screen sizes :) Do accept the answer and rate . Thank You

Comment: Thanks for your support Imran. But I found my own solution feel better to me.

Comment: Great that you have your best solution now. I actually thought you only need to do it this way. Otherwise CSS-Grid Masonry makes life a lot easy. Any ways happy for your my friend :) God Bless you

Comment: God Bless you too